# Как сделать replace вместо insertBatch для вставки/обновления несколько записей?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как сделать `replace` вместо `insertBatch` для вставки/обновления несколько записей?

`replace` не работает с многомерным массивом, он обновляет запись если совпадает первичный ключ, а также и просто вставляет запись.

`insertBatch` работает с многомерным массивом, но он просто вставляет записи.

```
// url c первичным ключем
$data = [
    ['url' => 'https://google.com/', 'name' => 'Google'],
    ['url' => 'https://yandex.com/', 'name' => 'Yandex'],
    // более 1000 записей
];
$builder = $this->db->table('posts');

$builder->replace($data); // не работает
```

CodeIgniter 4

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data